# Can't send data with AJAX to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to do detach some data from my database. I'm trying to send 2 different data to my controller with Ajax but couldn't make it. I need the `domain_id` and the `tag_id`.

Thats how it looks right now:

```
@foreach($domains as $domain)
    <tr>
        <td>
            @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
                <span><a href="#" data-tag-id="{{ $tag->id }}"
                         data-domain-id="{{ $domain->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a></span>
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Now I have the `domain_id` and the `tag_id` in the `<a>` tag. I'm trying to send both of them to my controller with Ajax, To detach them from my pivot table and thats it.

JS code:

```
$('a[data-tag-id]').click(function () {
    var tag_id = $(this).attr('data-tag-id');
    var domain_id = $(this).attr('data-domain-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'detaching',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {tag_id: tag_id, domain_id: domain_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('worked!');
        }
    });
});
```

Route Code:

```
Route::get('detaching', 'DomainController@detach2');
```

Controller Code:

```
public function detach2()
{
    $input =  Input::get('all');
    $domain = Domains::findOrFail($input['domain_id']);
    $domain->tags()->detach($input['tag_id']);
}
```

This don't work and I don't even know if the gets Ajax code called. I'm trying to `console.log()` some things out but I don't get anything back. I don't even know if the code reaches the controller function. I don't have much knowledge about Ajax or JS at all. Can someone maybe help me there?

---

LITTLE UPDATE

I've tried an easy:

```
$('a[data-tag-id]').click(function () {
    console.log('YES');
});
```

But this haven't worked either, So it doesn't jumps in the click function all I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, 
Give a class to your anchor tag like.

```
<a href="#" class="get-link" data-tag-id="{{ $tag->id }}" data-domain-id="{{ $domain->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
```

Change your route to

```
Route::get('detaching/{tag_id}/{domain_id}', 'DomainController@detach2');
```

Chnage your controller function to

```
public function detach2($tag_id, $domain_id)
{
    //$input =  Input::get('all');
    $domain = Domains::findOrFail($domain_id);
    $domain->tags()->detach($tag_id);
}
```

Change your JS file to

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).off('click', '.get-link');
        $(document).on('click', '.get-link', function () {
            var domain_id = $(this).data('domain-id');
            var tag_id = $(this).data('tag-id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'detaching'+ '/' + tag_id + '/' + domain_id + '/',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('worked!');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yes, this worked. Do you have a hint why my way didn't worked? thanks alot :)

Comment: the only thing that didn't work like I want is that I still can see the tag. It gets deleted from my database but I still can see it until the page gets reloaded. Is there a way to remove the tag so the user can't see it? would be cool if the whole tag disappears if the user klicks it

Comment: I've tried it with: `$('.get-link').hide();` but that of course hides every <a> tag with the get-link class

Comment: At my end this is working: 
`$('a[data-tag-id]').click(function () { console.log('YES');  });`
I think you might have issue with your other JS file.
And to hide the link you can simply write `$(this).hide();`